# for loop selenium python runs the last loop

Tags: python, selenium

My for loop goes to the latest part, and because the webpage needs the upper for loops to open so that the other for loops can operate, it doesn't work.

for x in browser.find_elements_by_class_name('node'):

```
x.click()

for y in  browser.find_elements_by_class_name('dTreeNode'):

    y.click()

if len(browser.find_elements_by_class_name('node')) > 0:

   browser.find_element_by_class_name('node').click()

                browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center[2]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/a[1]/img').click()
                browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center[2]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[4]/input').click()
                browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[5]/a').click()
                browser.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

This is the image:

[image]

In essence when the page goes back, it can't locate the last loop class and shows up an error because the element can only be found once I click on the previous element. But how do I do that inside the for loop?

Image of the HTML Text:

[image]

Comment: Please fix your code snippet indentation - in its current state it's invalid so no one can make sense of it

Comment: Can you paste error too?

Comment: @DeepakKumar it is a staleelement error

Answer (score 0):

It seems that either the `for y in  browser.find_elements_by_class_name('dTreeNode'):` returns an empty element or click is performed on a wrong element i.e. element is not programmed to receive the click.

Either case -

**First thing** - Please check if your first loop executing the code or not.

```
for y in  browser.find_elements_by_class_name('dTreeNode'):
    y.click()
    print('Clicked the element') #just for debugging
```

Then see if the element is returned or not.

Secondly - I see you are using absolute xPath. Can you convert it to relative xPath. Refer to [XPath Tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/xpath_overview.htm)

If you need help on xPath, update your question and HTML snippet of the expanded tree.

Comment: The thing is when my browser goes back to this page. It should first click the main element which will get me y element loop. Do you understand the issue? The loop works fine but how will it find the element if the main tree element is not clicked first.

Comment: That can be handled by defining a function for tree traversal. Maybe it always checks if tree is in the collapsed state. If yes then start from the top.

Another check can be added if element you are trying to click if visible or not

Comment: yes, that makes more sense, also, how do you select all elements under the select tag?

Comment: Can you share a bit more details about the tree? I think you can have a hierarichal element representation instead of only single element. For example: saying select "Sexo" you can specify that as "Todas las personas/Datos demograficos basicos/Sexo". So, each element to be selected shares compelete hierarchy instead of just one element

Comment: What can I share about the tree? The code or image?

Comment: HTML Code of expanded tree.

Comment: ok, thanks. Do you know how can I highlight/select all elements "options" under the select tag without the for loop?

Comment: Yup! use browser.find_elements_by_xpath and xpath .

Comment: @added the html text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209653/discussion-between-deepak-kumar-and-1010101010).